# Элементы и их получение

Tags: javascript

Когда элемент находится в html. В js мы его вызываем таким способом:

```
var a = document.getElementByID('label');
```

А если элемент, создается функцией которая записана в js, как вызвать данный элемент? Функция создающая элемент:

```
function creatElem()
{
    var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0];
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.id = 'label';
}
```

Функция которой требуется вызвать элемент Label, который создается функцией `creatElem()` (которая указана выше):

```
function label()
{
    var a = (и как переменной "а" присвоить элемент с id = 'label')
}
```

Применить `var a = document.getElementByID('label');` мы не можем.

Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш элемент находится только в памяти, поэтому из документа его вызвать и нельзя)

В общем случае:

```
function addElement(parent, tag, id) {
  var el = document.createElement(tag);
  el.setAttribute('id', id); // хоть убейте, не помню почему, но "очень рекомендуется"
  parent.appendChild(el);
  return document.getElementById(id);
  }
```

Вот так оно будет работать.

Примечание раз: для добавления дива в тело документа, пример:

```
var myDiv1 = addElement(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0], 'div', 'mydiv');
```

Примечание два: после этого див будет доступен по `getElementById`.

Примечание три, на всякий случай: учитывайте, что id должен быть уникален в границах документа. Удалить элемент можно так:

```
var el = document.getElementById('mydiv');
el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
```

Comment: Жаль не могу плюсик вам кинуть, спасибо большое.

Comment: Так вы можете ответ принять =) Галку слева от ответа нажмите)

Comment: el.setAttribute('id', id); // хоть убейте, не помню почему, но "очень рекомендуется"

Все очень просто - Вы указываете, что атрибут id (имя) создаваемого объекта должен равняться тому значению id, которое было передано в качестве параметра функции AddElement. Так, например, это может быть - label1, label2 и т.д.

Comment: Я не об этом - я не помню, почему не "`div.id = id;`". Скорее всего, что-то с IE связано, он вроде как некоторые атрибуты просто так отказывается присваивать.

Comment: Функцию добавил, теперь зашел в 

function creatElem()
{
var myDiv1 = addElement(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0], 'div', 'mydiv');
}
Всё верно?

Comment: Так это, пробуйте) написано верно, а что вы дальше с ним делать будете - не знаю.